# Run Java File at Runtime

Tags: java, class, runtime

I want to run a java file provided by the user of my application at runtime.

I tried:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac MyClass.java");
p1.waitFor();
Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java MyClass");
p2.waitFor();
```

But it doesn't work. It creates a Class File, but it doesnt create a binary file.

Any suggestion?

I'll precise what I am doing:

So here is my java file:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("My Method Called");
    }
}
```

And here is my code trying to compile and execute this class:

```
 public class TestExecute {

    private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(name + " " + line);
        }
      }

      private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        pro.waitFor();
        System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          runProcess("javac MyClass.java");
          runProcess("java MyClass");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

}
```

In the path, MyClass.class is created. Hier is the output in the console:

```
javac C:/Users/Maher/workspace/1/src/main/java/model/MyClass.java exitValue() 0
```

I am using eclipse on Windows 7.

And I want to display "My Method Called" to test this solution but it wasn't displayed.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: The class file is a binary file.

Comment: The class file indeed is a binary file. This works fine on my computer.

Comment: Also note there is an API to access the Java compiler: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting *output* of compiled or running java class then you have to read the `InputStream` of child process.

```
 Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java MyClass");
 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));

 String line=null;
 while( (line=br.readLine())!=null)
  {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
 p2.waitFor();
```

EDIT: Add `main()` method.

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(){
        System.out.println("My Method Called");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
       new MyClass().myMethod();
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Mahermassaabi - You need to add an entry point - `main()` method in MyClass to launch the *MyClass*.

Comment: I think that you should handle stderr too:
`InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();`
Maybe you run command with wrong arguments.
Also I suggest that main method must looks like this:
`public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("My Method Called");
    }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You could consider another approach. Java has a scripting API for embedding JavaScript, Python etcetera. Now, [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) is java.

It is faster and less brittle than using exec twice.